# How to avoid Unsupported subquery error in snow flake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working On a SQL query in snowflake.
​

```
With A as ( ),
B as (),
C as ( select * from B
Left join X on B.id = x.id
Left join Y on B.id = Y.Eid
​Left join Z on Z .uid = Y.Eid and Z.Date in (
Select min(Date) from Z1 where Z1.id = Y.Eid and Z1.Date = B.Date))​
```

​
W​hen I execute the above query I'm getting this error:

> Unsupported Subquery type cannot be evaluated

- As of my knowledge the issue with `CTE c`, how can I rewrite that part

Comment: Your final subquery can only return one value so why are you using IN rather than = ?

Comment: is it the complete SQL? It looks like partial SQL. you must have something like this - `.... select * from C` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

move the sub-select into a global min for each combination, is one method, like so:

```
With A as ( ),
B as (),
min_dates as (
  Select
    Z1.id,
    Z1.Date,
    min(Date) as min_date
  from Z1 
  group by 1,2
),
C as ( 
  select * 
  from B
  Left join X 
    on B.id = x.id
  Left join Y 
    on B.id = Y.Eid
  left join min_dates as M
    on M.id = Y.Eid and M.Date = B.Date
  ​Left join Z 
    on Z.uid = Y.Eid 
      and Z.Date = M.min_date
)​
SELECT * FROM C;
```

But for your example code, this is pointless, as `MIN(date)` per date is just `date` because you are matching per date.

```
Select min(Date) from Z1 where Z1.id = Y.Eid and Z1.Date = B.Date)
```

this code is saying when `z1.date = X` find the min value for `min(z1.date)`, that will be X, so unless min(date) is a different column than z1.date, then the above code could drop that new CTE and just use b.Date on the Z join:

```
With A as ( ),
B as (),
C as ( 
  select * 
  from B
  Left join X 
    on B.id = x.id
  Left join Y 
    on B.id = Y.Eid
  left join Z1 as z1
    on z1.id = Y.Eid and z1.Date = B.Date
  ​Left join Z 
    on Z.uid = Y.Eid 
      and Z.Date = z1.Date 
)​
SELECT * FROM C;
```